# Enter key triggering the Login button

Tags: c#, winforms

My login form has 4 controls. The user can input name, password and enter on button for login.

I'd like the Enter key to trigger the Login action after the Name and Password textboxes are filled out.

How can this be done? Trying to avoid `btnLogin.Focus()` under the TextBox event.

[image: screen]

Answer (score 34, accepted):

On your form you can set the AcceptButton property to the login button.

Comment: FYI add to the form_load: `this.AcceptButton = btnLogin;`

Answer (score 7):

Set the form's **AcceptButton** property to be the Login button. When the user hits Enter, the Click event for that button will be triggered. The **CancelButton** property is the one you want for your Cancel button.

Again, these are properties of the Form, not the buttons.

Answer (score 2):

```
    private void txtCost_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        //MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(e.KeyValue));

            if (e.KeyValue == 13)
            {
                command;
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

yOU CAN USE KEY PRESS event like this so whenever user press enter the event will fire.

```
private void txtMessage_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyChar.Equals(Convert.ToChar(13)))
            {
                btnLogin_Click(sender, e);
            }
        }
```

Comment: if you want to doing it by writing the code this the way to do it..thats it..so whenever you are in the password textbox and press enter login click will fire.thats all..

Answer (score 0):

Just Move your code to panel and set panel property DefaultButton="btnLogIn" Like

```
`<asp:Panel ID="pnlLogin" runat="server" DefaultButton="btnLogIn">
```